# What is the way to get the first finish future from a list of future in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, future

The following way of iterating a list of future always wait for the first job to be done:

```
for (Future<MyFutureResult> future : list) {
    List<MyFutureResult> result = future.get();
}
```

Is there a way to iterate all the finish job first?

Comment: Is list of type `List<Future<List<MyFutureResult>>>`? Are you sure you don't mean something like `for (Future<?> future : list)`?

Comment: if the "Future<MyFutureResult>" is actually "CompletableFuture<MyFutureResult>" which allows asynchronous reading, then you can make finished futures to put results in a "LinkedBloackingQueue<MyFutureResult> resultQueue "with "future.whenComplete((v,e){resultQueue.put(v);}); and then read the results using "MyFutureResult = resultQueue.take();".

Answer (score 7):

Getting the first completed `Future` from the list of futures is not possible directly since those are processed in parallel and you would have to block anwyay to find the result.

However you could have control over task completion by using [`ExecutorsCompletionService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) for your parallel processing. This class has `take` and `poll` methods that return `Future` of next completed task :

> A `CompletionService` that uses a supplied `Executor` to execute tasks. **This class arranges that submitted tasks are, upon completion, placed on a queue accessible using `take`**. The class is lightweight enough to be suitable for transient use when processing groups of tasks.

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

CompletionService<Integer> ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(threadPool);

int tasks = 10;

IntStream.range(0, tasks)
            .forEach(i -> ecs.submit(() -> i)); // submit tasks

for(int i = 0; i < tasks; i++) {
    Future<Integer> take = ecs.take(); // this is blocking operation but futures are returned in completion order. Also you will have to handle InterruptedException
}

// remember to close the ExecutorService after you are done
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into `ExecutorService.invokeAny(..)` that returns the first result, or `ExecutorService.invokeAll(..)` that returns all completed tasks (within a timeout).

```
class InvokeAnyAllTest {

    ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    // create some Callable tasks
    List<Callable<MyFutureResult>> tasks = IntStream.range(0, 10) //
            .mapToObj(this::createTask)
            .collect(toList());

    private Callable<MyFutureResult> createTask(int i) {
        return () -> new MyFutureResult(i);
    }

    @Test
    void testFirstCallable() throws Exception {
        MyFutureResult result = es.invokeAny(tasks);
        assertTrue(result.i >= 0 && result.i < 10);
    }

    @Test
    void testAllCompleted() throws Exception {
        List<Future<MyFutureResult>> results = es.invokeAll(tasks, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // all futures that are done within 5s, either normally or by throwing an exception
        Set<Integer> values = results.stream().map(f -> {
            try {
                return f.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // are we interested in failed ones too?
            }
            return null;
        }).filter(Objects::nonNull).map(result -> result.i).collect(toSet());

        IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> assertTrue(values.contains(i)));
    }

    // in case we have only futures, not callables
    @Test
    void testFirstFuture() throws Exception {
        // create futures
        List<Future<MyFutureResult>> futures = IntStream.range(0, 10) //
                .mapToObj(i -> es.submit(createTask(i)))
                .collect(toList());

        // turn futures into callables
        List<Callable<MyFutureResult>> callables = futures.stream()
                .map(f -> (Callable<MyFutureResult>) () -> f.get())
                .collect(toList());

        MyFutureResult result = es.invokeAny(callables);
        assertTrue(result.i >= 0 && result.i < 10);
    }

    private static class MyFutureResult {

        int i;

        public MyFutureResult(int i) {
            this.i = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by any reason you are not supposed to use ExecutorsCompletionService (as mentioned by Michał Krzywański). Then you can replace ecs.take() or future.get() with below method.

```
getCompletedFuture(futureSet, 1000).get();
 .
 .
 .
private static Future<V> getCompletedFuture(Set<Future<V>> futureSet, long pollInterval)
            throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Iterator<Future<V>> iterator = futureSet.iterator();
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
                iterator = futureSet.iterator();
            }
            try {
                V v = iterator.next().get(pollInterval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                if (v != null) {
                    iterator.remove();
                    return iterator.next();
                }
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        throw new InterruptedException();
    }
```

Comment: This "solution" has the unfortunate property that if you have N futures in the set, it can take up to N x pollInterval milliseconds (after the first completion) to find a completed future.  Furthermore, there is a good chances that it won't be the *first* future to complete.

Comment: (If you can't use `ExecutorsCompletionService` and the future is not a `CompletableFuture`, then there is no solution that doesn't have ... problems.)

Answer (score 0):

You can put the futures onto a `BlockingQueue` in order of their completion.

```
public static <T> BlockingQueue<CompletableFuture<T>> collect(Stream<CompletableFuture<T>> futures) {
    var queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<CompletableFuture<T>>();
    futures.forEach(future ->
        future.handle((success, failure) -> queue.add(future)));

    return queue;
}
```

Each call to `BlockingQueue.take` on the queue returned by `collect` will block until the next future become available by completing and return that future.